# 'that' is not the same as 'this' when passed, why?

Tags: javascript, class, this

```
//class bar
//(construtor)
go(res, err){
    //functions that use 'this'
    console.log(this); 
} 
foo(article){ 
    //do stuff
    var that = this;
    var sorting = {
        sort: function(t){
            //do stuff
            console.log(that); //looks exactly like 'bar'
            return that;
        },
        go: that.go //ERROR: want this.go, got foo.sorting
    }
    return sorting;
}
```

why does

```
new bar.foo('x').sort();
```

work fine and show 'that' & 'this' as 'bar', but

```
new bar.foo('x').go();
```

does not work and (afaik) returns foo's 'this'?

how do I route

```
new bar.foo('x').go();
```

to be the same as

```
new bar.go();
```

?

Comment: Is it possible to assign `this.sorting` instead of a local variable? When you chain like this you can mess up the chain if you return an instance other than itself.

Comment: @tadman `bar` has multiple "foo" functions that have different types of sorting options, so for simplicity `bar.fooX.sort()` is the syntax for multiple functions. Is this bad practice?

Comment: I always try and engineer things so that `return this` is at the end of any method designed to be chained. This often means maintaining an internal state which can be messy if overlapping calls are happening. I'm not sure what your general objective is here.

Comment: @tadman yes, I am starting to wish all functions returned the "bar" this and didn't require a "pair" function to get back to that root.,. It'd be great if I could merge "foo this" with "bar this"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the `this` value so that `this` doesn't become the `sorting` object.

```
var sorting = {
    sort: function(t){
        console.log(that);
        return that;
    },
    go: that.go.bind(that)
}
```

Comment: This works! thanks! You're saying `that` was being "redefined" to `sorting`?

Comment: @Ben `that` never changes once you set it, but `this` will change depending on what object the function is called from (unless you `bind` it).